# how to run django-simple-blog?

Tags: python, django

How to run Django-simple-blog? I tried to install django-simple-blog but could not find the manage.py file to run it. Can I get a solution or another simple blog?

Comment: How did you install it  https://github.com/drager/django-simple-blog#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a concept of apps and a concept of projects.  A project will have a manage.py file like you mention, and will also have a settings.py file that declares all of the apps that the project uses.

django-simple-blog is an app, meaning you install it within an existing project. After this explaination, the rest of the steps found here should be easier to follow: https://github.com/drager/django-simple-blog/blob/master/README.rst

The remaining steps are to:

- Add 'simpleblog' to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py file
- run the command `python manage.py migrate` from your project root
- include 'simpleblog.urls' into any of your `urls.py` file

Comment: thanks for help friend. i think i thanks friend. after your answer i remember about django. i forget if django-simple-blog is app. and we can add on my project. thanks you

Comment: Glad my answer helpped. Please mark it as correct :)